# XposedBridge Crash Report, How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-imageview, xposed

I got this error report in `Crashlytics`.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.view.main.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class ImageView

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2665)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main (XposedBridge.java:107)

Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class ImageView

Caused by android.view.InflateException
Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class ImageView

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f081080

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Unable to find resource ID #0x7f081080

android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName (ResourcesImpl.java:228)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:518)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative (XposedBridge.java)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod (XposedBridge.java:360)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java)
androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate (DataBindingUtil.java:95)
com.example.view.main.fragment.InitFragment.onCreateView (InitFragment.java:137)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreateAnimator (Fragment.java:8)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:178)
com.example.view.main.MainActivity.onStart (MainActivity.java:147)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main (XposedBridge.java:107)
```

The things that I think weirdly is `xposed` and `XposedBridge`. I looked for what it is and I figured it out that is used after rooting the device t o change its behaviour or UI. Check [here](https://github.com/rovo89/Xposed)

Is it worth to correspond rooted deviced as well? I think I can just ignore it. What's your opinion and if there's some solution for this problem. How can I do it?

Comment: If this is only happening on rooted devices with xposed installed I would silently ignore this report.

Comment: Hello, i have the same issue that is reported in crashlytics, my application is live on play store more then 8 month, but i found this crash for the first time only 1 users is affected with mode Galaxy S8+ Android version 5.1.1 , any help to fix this would be appreciated Thanks

Comment: I think you can just ignore that issue. What I thought is there's some users who root their phones to change their UI, which is... you don't need to care. What you can avoid this, check if the user's device is rooted or not and block that user. I experimented with it and many mobile games they block this way and shows pop up. But, I don't think it can hack your service data or something and no harmful stuffs. So, I just let it be. (But Crashlystics said it's not rooted at the time. That's weird.)

Answer (score -1):

how to fix

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>   Unable to find resource ID #0x7f081080

search your project for the generated rescoureid "0x7f081080" (probably some .../generated/.../R.java) which will translate the missing-resource-ID to symbolic-id

i.e.

```
public static final int my_image_id=0x7f081080;
```

then search again you project for that symbolic-id where you probably find sind xml-layout-file or some java code that uses the resource

what to do next depends on the code that uses the resource

Comment: Well, I think `xpose` generates that kind of thing. I don't have that ID and No #32 line in the xml file.